# Redirect Different Log Frameworks Output to a File

Tags: java, logging

I'm working on a project that uses different log frameworks, for example: log4j, commons-logging ... and our project log. Is there any way to redirect all those different logs in a special class to a file to get all the log info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use slf4j and it's bridging modules for these 'legacy' frameworks http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html. From memory, if you were using log4j as your primary framework, you drop in a log4j slf4j binding, and the commons bridge, and that'd have the result of getting all of your commons-logging events to the log4j root category logger.